# Design aspects when exposing API's

Tags: c, api, function-pointers

I am trying to understand the design strategies employed in a third-party software. In specific, I am analyzing a case where a code in the **"IMPLEMENTATION_LAYER"** (say) of the software stack implements certain functionality (via c routines) and exposes the signatures of those routines as API's to the **"APPLICATION LAYER"**  for its use. This is done in the following way

The application layer is provided with the following sructure

```
struct my_interfaces
{
    /*List of function pointers*/
};
```

and a list of macro based functions to initialize this structure (with the suitable functions) and access the methods of this structure.

**Questions**

What is the advantage of exposing API's in this way,compared to the legacy method.The legacy method I mean by,exposing just prototypes of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Minimal API Exports**: You don't need to export an entire library; just a "GetAPI" api.
- **Versioned APIS**: The API-loader can be told which "version" of the API is being requested, therefore exposing both features and behavior specific to a specific version request
- **Modular APIS**: The API loader can load other modules dynamically and wire requested APIS from those .so/.dll files on the fly.
- **Centralized Licensing**: A single API loader radically reduces the number of places licensed code checks need to be performed.
- **Mode Switching**: Depending on the APIs requested, different functionality can be loaded or not loaded. Partial API population, in other words. A good example of this would be a crypto library entering FIPS-mode where only a specific subset of qualified algorithms will be accessible, and all others are stubbed to be error conditions.

Those are just a few off the top of my head